# How is radius of curvature defined at the end of a circular path?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, curvature

This is my first time asking a question here, apologies in advance.

How is the radius of curvature defined at the end of a circular path? For example, take a particle moving on a semi-circular path which terminates in a straight line. At the point where the circular path and the straight path starts, how would radius of curvature be defined?

[image]

The above is a diagram of a semi-circular done on which lies a ball of mass $m$. All surfaces are assumed frictionless and we were to find the angle $\theta$ at which the ball loses contact with the dome after being given a slight nudge to the right.

In this question, at the angle $\theta$ when the block loses contact with the dome, how can we say the radius of curvature is equal to $R$ (in the frame of the dome)? Is radius or curvature not defined as the radius of the circular path in which the particle moves, here at the moment the contact is lost the radius of curvature would change at every moment.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know anything of calculus. But your point is that at the end of a circular path the radius of curvature isn't really defined?

In that case, for a particle thrown into the air (parabolic path under gravity), would the radius of curvature be undefined for each point along its path? But is it not possible to find the radius by using the component of gravity as centripetal acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

At some critical angle $\theta_c$ the point-mass $m$ looses the contact to the circle. Up to this point the radius of curvature is $R$. Beyond this point the radius of curvature is greater than $R$. Thus the question is: Is the radius of curvature
(*i*) a continuous function, or
(*ii*) a discontinuous function?

At the point of last contact the centrifugal force is equal to the projection of the gravitational force -- using the projection angle $\theta_c$. Thus, at this point then radius of curvature is still $R$. At the angle $\theta_c + \epsilon$ the centrifugal force overcomes the projected component. Thus, the radius of curvature will be $R+R_\epsilon$. Hence, the radius of curvature is a continuous function. Does this make sense to you?